# Create html link that starts the navigation on mobile phone using native app

Tags: html, google-maps, map-directions

I want to add a link on my website to start a navigation to the specific coordinates or to show some icon on that coordinates, so you can see your position and the position you need with a big zoom (it will be used when the person is near it). I tried:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@44.13547940000001,9.6813342,21z
```

it openes the map with a center on my coordinates, but I don't have an icon to understand where is that place... I cannot navigate to it. I tried without (or with different) zoom too.

```
geo:44.13547940000001,9.6813342?z=8
geo:44.13547940000001,9.6813342?daddr=(44.13547940000001,9.6813342)
```

This one opens Google Earth (if I uninstall it - it doesn't work)! So I cannot navigate and I don't see where is it, the position in in the center but...

Is there a possibility to open google maps / app with an icon on the coordinates I want to share. Or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link:
https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=45.464167,9.191389&q=45.464167,9.191389&hl=en&t=h&z=18

It openes google app and points a mark.